# Resource that use two different services and query with pagination when resolved

Tags: angular.js, coffeescript, pagination

I'm learning Angular and I don't like my current approach. The current controller uses first `Geolocation` service and when `getLocation()` is resolved, then the `Pagination` service is invoked with the location param. Is it any better solution to provide one service that query server with location? Can I integrate the `Pagination` service to call it through the `Post` factory with a resolved location?

```
angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','Post','Pagination','Geolocation'
  ($scope, Post, Pagination, Geolocation) ->
    $scope.posts = []
    Geolocation.getLocation().then (location) ->
      Pagination.paginate $scope, Post, 10, (postsRes) ->
        $scope.posts.push posts for posts in postsRes
      , params: {location: location}
])

angular.module('app').factory 'Post', ($resource) ->
  $resource '/posts/:id.json', { id: '@id' }

angular.module('app').service "Geolocation", ['$q', '$window', ($q, $window) ->
  @getLocation = ->
    deferred = $q.defer()
    return deferred.resolve @loc if @loc
    if $window.navigator and $window.navigator.geolocation
      $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (position) ->
        @loc = position.coords
        deferred.resolve position.coords

    deferred.promise
]
angular.module('app').service 'Pagination', ->
  @paginate = ($scope, @resource, @maxElemPerPage=10, @onNewPage, @query={}) ->
    @page = 1
    @canLoadNextPage = true
    $scope.loadPage = (promise) =>
      return promise.resolve() unless @canLoadNextPage
      @load promise

    @load = (promise) =>
      @canLoadNextPage = false
      q = angular.extend @query, page: @page
      @resource.query q, (resources) =>
        @canLoadNextPage = true if resources.length is @maxElemPerPage
        @page++
        @onNewPage resources if @onNewPage
        promise.resolve() if promise

    @load()
  @
```